# Вывод новостей из инфоблока в зависимости от входных параметров

Tags: php, битрикс

Есть компонент news.list, он подключен так:

```
<div><?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:news.list", ".default", array(
"IBLOCK_TYPE" => "SMS",
"IBLOCK_ID" => "181",
"NEWS_COUNT" => "10",
"SORT_BY1" => "ACTIVE_FROM",
"SORT_ORDER1" => "DESC",
"SORT_BY2" => "SORT",
"SORT_ORDER2" => "ASC",
"FILTER_NAME" => "",
"FIELD_CODE" => array(
    0 => "",
    1 => "",
),
"PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
    0 => "TEXT_SMS",
    1 => "TELEFON",
    2 => "TEXT_TEMPLATE",
    3 => "",
),
"CHECK_DATES" => "Y",
"DETAIL_URL" => "",
"AJAX_MODE" => "N",
"AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",
"AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "Y",
"AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",
"CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
"CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
"CACHE_FILTER" => "N",
"CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
"PREVIEW_TRUNCATE_LEN" => "",
"ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => "d.m.Y",
"SET_STATUS_404" => "N",
"SET_TITLE" => "Y",
"INCLUDE_IBLOCK_INTO_CHAIN" => "Y",
"ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "Y",
"HIDE_LINK_WHEN_NO_DETAIL" => "N",
"PARENT_SECTION" => "",
"PARENT_SECTION_CODE" => "",
"INCLUDE_SUBSECTIONS" => "Y",
"PAGER_TEMPLATE" => ".default",
"DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
"DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "Y",
"PAGER_TITLE" => "Шаблоны",
"PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => "Y",
"PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => "N",
"PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME" => "36000",
"PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "Y",
"DISPLAY_DATE" => "Y",
"DISPLAY_NAME" => "Y",
"DISPLAY_PICTURE" => "Y",
"DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT" => "Y",
"AJAX_OPTION_ADDITIONAL" => ""
),
false
);?></div>
```

Так же есть массив входных параметров GET запроса:

```
Array
(
  [bitrix_include_areas] => Y
  [useExtraFilter] => true
  [date_fld_start] => 15.09.2016
  [date_fld_end] => 15.09.2016
  [state] => 
  [destinationAddress] => 
  [clear_cache] => Y
)
```

Подскажите, как организовать вывод элементов, в завсимости от параметров GET запроса. Т.е., 1) надо чтобы ввывелесь все элементы, у которых `ACTIVE_FROM < $_GET['date_fld_end'] AND ACTIVE_FROM > $_GET['date_fld_start']`, а также если `$_GET['destinationAddress']` не пустой, чтобы также вывелись элементы, где `PROPERTY_CODE[1]` равен  `$_GET['destinationAddress']` (здесь не знаю как правильно записать), при этом свойство `TELEFON` - множественное

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы реализовать такой отбор Вам нужно воспользоваться полем `"FILTER_NAME"` компонента в которое необходимо передать фильтр отбора записей.
Пример как такое сделать можете посмотреть [здесь](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=5186&), [здесь](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/content/iblock/components_2/news/news_list.php), [здесь](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/filters/date.php) и [здесь](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=2683)

В Вашем случае примерный вид для фильтрации будет такой:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['destinationAddress'] != '') { 
    $propForFilter = $_GET['destinationAddress'];
}
global $arNewsFilter;
$arNewsFilter = array(
    "><DATE_ACTIVE_FROM" => array(
        date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    ),
    "PROPERTY_CODE" => $propForFilter,
);
?>
```

Это пример фильтра.

Вы можете расширять этот массив в зависимости от условий. Для фильтрации по свойствам используйте описание свойства в формате `PROPERTY_CODE => array(//значения которые принимает свойство)`.